# CORS problem, but only on one endpoint and only in Windows

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, cors, django-cors-headers

I have a Django backend (using Django REST Framework), and a SvelteKit frontend that talks to it. Everything works perfectly fine in all browsers across Windows and macOS, all POST and DELETE requests and all that have the correct CORS headers.

Except the endpoint to upload images. That one doesn't seem to work for Windows users, in Edge, Chrome, or Firefox.

The endpoint uses Django REST Framework's `APIView`, just like many other endpoints.

```py
class ImageUploadParser(FileUploadParser):
    media_type = "image/*"

    def get_filename(self, stream, media_type, parser_context):
        # We create our own filename, and we get the extension based on the actual file type
        return "unused.nope"


class ImageUploadView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    parser_classes = [ImageUploadParser]

    def post(self, request):
        # [A bunch of logic to upload the file...]

        return Response({"url": f"{relative_path}/{filename}"}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

I've set up `corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware` and its `CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS` setting. Like I said, all other endpoints work fine, and the upload endpoint also works fine under macOS (Safari, Edge and Firefox).

This is the network inspector in Safari:

[image]

And this is Edge on Windows:

[image]

What could cause this one endpoint to not work, and only in Windows? How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think it could be the difference in **file size**. in your Windows inspector says `content-length: 1132500` and the Safari one says `content-length: 86348`.

did you upload the same file?

references: [about 413](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/413)

Comment: You're absolutely right - the image I used in Window to test was indeed pretty big. The console had an error about CORS headers so that threw me off but you're right, it's the 413 Content Too Large that's the problem.

Comment: hi @KevinRenskers, I'm glad I was able to answer your question!  I sometimes experience moments where i go "why did i miss this?" when realizing something plainly in sight only after my colleague next to me point it out. haha

Comment: Uploading the same file in macOS indeed gives the same error. It's weird though: the file is only 1MB big and the max payload size in Django is 2.5MB. So I wonder what is triggering this error.

Comment: And to answer myself: Nginx defaults to a max 1 MB 